# Вывести элементы в виде таблицы WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как расположить элементы через Binding  в виде таблицы? DataGrid не предлагайте, не подходит.

Когда делаю вручную

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTable.MyRows}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Cells.Count}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[0].Text}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[1].Text}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[2].Text}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[3].Text}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cells[4].Text}"/>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Всё работает.
[image: Работает]
Если пробую биндить, не выходит

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTable.MyRows}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Cells.Count}">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

[image: Не выходит]

Что делаю не так? Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Можно и отключить, так-то

Comment: @Сергей Допустим даже если я строки буду через ListView выводить, как это решит мою проблему с ячейками?

Comment: Я понял, что проблема в том, что ItemsControl добавляет панель и уже в неё кидает элементы

Comment: поменяйте панель (внутреннюю) на горизонтальную StackPanel

Comment: А почему у вас заголовки строк расположены среди данных? Вы изобретаете велосипед, кстати, вам нужно по идее [вот это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-display-listview-contents-by-using-a-gridview).

Comment: @VladD насколько понимаю вложенный ItemsControl был выбран из-за того что количество столбцов может быть разным

Comment: @FoggyFinder Тогда элементы в каждой строке идут подряд и не форматируются под общую таблицу

Comment: да, поэтому я и не написал ответ, мой комментарий был скорее к тому почему так происходит. Я бы просто попробовал использовал [DataGrid2D](https://github.com/GuOrg/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте я всё же набросаю пример с `GridView`.

Начнём со структуры данных. Я отделю заголовки столбцов от информации в столбцах.

Выходит:

```
class Table
{
    public string[] Headers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string[]> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Окей, у нас переменное количество столбцов, которое мы не знаем. Тогда сгенерируем столбцы на лету. Чтобы получать нотификацию, когда свойство `Headers` поменяется, воспользуемся трюком с невидимым элементом. (Чтобы это работало, ваш класс `Table` должен ещё и поддерживать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`!)

Наш XAML получается совсем простым.

```
<Grid Visibility="Collapsed" Name="Dummy" DataContext="{Binding Headers}"
      DataContextChanged="OnRowsChanged"/>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" Name="List">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" x:Name="GridView"/>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Ну и немного code-behind:

```
void OnRowsChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var rows = (IEnumerable<string>)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
    GridView.Columns.Clear();

    int no = 0;
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        GridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn()
            {
                Header = row,
                DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding($"[{no}]")
            });
        no++;
    }
}
```

Получается:

[image: а клёвый трюк с невидимым элементом, да?]

Answer (score 0):

Если есть исходная коллекция почему не замапить в то что нам надо

```
collection.Select(element => new 
{
    // тут делаем как будет выглядить элемент
})
```